# Editing the selected option in the select dropdown(<q-select> of quasar framework)

Tags: vuejs2, quasar-framework

I am trying the edit the previously selected option in the select drop down.I am able to show the checked options based on the data driven from the service call, but not able to choose other select option in the drop down.I am using quasar framework and vue.js.
Code:

```
<q-select
 multiple 
stack-label="Actions"
v-model="multiSelect"
:options="options"/>
```

Script:

```
import {QCheckbox,QSelect} from 'quasar'export
 default {components: {QCheckbox,QSelect},
data () {return {
multSelect: [],
options1: [{label: 'X-B',value: 'x-b'},{label: 'RT-Builder',value: 'rt-builder'},{label: 'Com',value: 'com'},{label: 'Max',value: 'max'},{label: 'Runner',value: 'runner'},{label: 'Opto',value: 'opto'}],
....................
created () {
axios.get('http://*********/getDetails').then(response => {
this.multiSelect = response.data
})
}
```

Can someone help me with this?

Answer (score 1):

The value you store in your component property `multiSelect` should be an array of the selectable *values* you want to be checked:

For example (following your data set):

```
this.multiSelect = ['x-b', 'rt-builder', 'max']
```

Whereas for "simple" select fields (single choice)

```
<q-select ... v-model="selectedValue" :options="options" />
```

you simply do

```
this.selectedValue = 'identifier'
```

Comment: Hi, I tried doing something like this and what the docs say but i want the normal value, label type of select, then just pass the id to the api backend but cant seem to get this working when i give the value of the selected item it just shows the id. Please see here: https://codepen.io/ettienne/pen/VJXKNE

Comment: @Louwki Your property "model" is a number (`1`) whereas in your "options" array, the "values" are strings (`'1'`, `'2'`, ...). Make their types consistent (either all number or all strings) and it works as expected.

Comment: ah what a silly mistake, they always say a fresh pair of eyes is sometimes all you need :), Thanx alot